# CiviBanking «dry run» missing

Tags: civibanking

In the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/banking/en/latest/configuration/plugins/importers/xml/#test-configuration) it is explained that you could do «dry runs».

This option is missing for me. Is there a setting or something I have missed, explaining why it isn’t showing?

I am on CiviCRM 5.20.0 and CiviBanking 0.7-alpha6